# Remove the frame on clickable HTML elements

Tags: html, css, focus, out

I would like to know if there is any way to remove the dotted frame (on Firefox) around an HTML clickable element (a, button, etc.) that appears when you click, hold click and focus it.

Thank you

Comment: maybe you are looking for something like this: `button:focus { outline: none; }`

Comment: Perfect, thank you sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove outlines across the components ( links, button, clickable images, input fields, etc ) with the following CSS.

```
*:focus {
outline: none;
}
```